# What can I do to get the #factorial div have css properties specified in the header

Tags: javascript, css

Here is the html document. why doesn't css properties specified in the header execute?
what can i do to make them work (properties: "border-radius:4px;background-color:#1B35E0;")

```
 <!DOCTYPE>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript|Practice</title>
    <style type="text/css"><!--Here goes inner design with CSS-->
        #factorial {
            border-radius:4px;
            background:yellow;
            }
    </style>
    <script>
        //Recursion
        //---------
        var x;
        var factorialValue;

        function start(){
            var startButton=document.getElementById("start");
            startButton.addEventListener("click",getInput,false);
        }
        function getInput(){
            x=window.prompt("Enter a positive integer");
            factorialValue=doRecursion(x);
            displayResult(factorialValue);

        }
        function doRecursion(n){
            if(n<=1){
                return 1;
            }
            else
                return n*doRecursion(n-1);
        }
        function displayResult(result){

            var output = "<p>"+x+"!="+result+" </p>";
            document.getElementById("factorial").innerHTML=output;
        }
        window.addEventListener("load",start,false);
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <p>Factorial number Calculator</p>
        <input id="start" type="button" value="Start" />
        <p id="factorial"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is `start()` defined? when is `displayResult` called? with no content, you won't see either of those styles on the div.

Comment: Side note, you're closing your `<p>` tag with a `</div>`

Comment: Also so your elements are mismatched. Your factorial 'div' is opened with a 'p' tag.

Comment: Demos should be a requirement for JS related questions:  http://jsfiddle.net/4DDjS/

Comment: @Dave I think i made some important edit to my question. Is anything else should I do to be clear and get an answer?

Comment: I think for the color I mentioned, I used a different one (yellow) in the code too, hope it doesn't bother anyone.

Comment: Also, be careful in that comments inside style (CSS) use /* */ and not <!-- -->

Comment: @cimmanon your JSfiddle was close to working. You just needed to change the JS to No wap - in <head>.  http://jsfiddle.net/4DDjS/1/

Comment: Putting a `<p>` inside another `<p>` is a bad idea, because they're both blocks. Change your JS code to use `<span>` or nothing at all. Other than that, I think DigitalD has already shown you a working version.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `<!--Here goes inner design with CSS-->` you've included a html comment inside of the css tags. `<!-- -->` is not css comment syntax.